# Mention users with specific role in bot status

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Sooo, hello to everyone who sees this, it's my first time posting anything on StackOverflow. Anyway, recently I started learning discord.js and I managed to create a small bot in v12 with automatically changing status. Here is the code:

```
setInterval(() => {
    const statuses = [
      `user 1`,
      `user 2`,
      `user 3...`
    ]

    const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
    client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING" })
  }, 5000)
```

The point is to have certain members usernames appear in bot status and this is really nice if the server has like just a few of these "special" members but now my server became larger and I would like for bot to target ONE specific role and list all the members with that "special" role :)
Please help me, thank you in advance

So after Elitezen tried to help me I did this:

I added async in client on ready:

```
client.on("ready", async () => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("SERVER_ID");
```

I added your code:

```
const role = guild.roles.cache.get('SERVER_ID');

  await guild.members.fetch();

setInterval(() => {
    const statuses = Array
       .from(role.members.cache.values())
       .map(member => member.displayName);

    const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
    client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING" })
  }, 5000)
```

And now Im stuck with this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example to target your desired role using `RoleManager#get()` or `RoleManager#find()`

```js
const role = <Guild>.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'role name');
// Or
const role = <Guild>.roles.cache.get('role id');
```

To get all the members that hold this role fetch all members of the guild first, then construct an array from the Collection's values.

Then map the array of members to their display name (or user's username)

Ensure you have the guild member's intent enabled if you want to fetch all members.

```js
await <Guild>.members.fetch();

setInterval(() => {
    const statuses = Array
       .from(role.members.values());
       .map(member => member.displayName);

    const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
    client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING" })
  }, 5000)
```

Comment: This, my friend, I'm sure solves my problem. Tho now comes another problem caused by my beginner knowledge in node.js. When I implement your code I get an error saying that I have an await function yet I do not know where to implement async function...

Comment: I will try to google that since I am positive this is a must-know basic thing to do. If you do decide to explain that as well tho... Thank you im advance, God bless you

Comment: Edited my question above with more informations after implementing your code :(

Comment: I've edited my answers, seems that the `cache` property no longer exists on `Role#members`

Comment: BRO IT WORKS!!! Legend! You're a legend to me, thank you so so much, God bless you

Comment: @Elitezen `Role#members` is a getter, never had `.cache`. It always got the cached members in a guild, and filtered them by if they have the role

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to Elitezen I managed to solve my problem.

After making client on ready an async function

```
client.on("ready", async () => {
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("SERVER_ID");
```

This is the final script for mentioning users with a certain role in bot status:

```
const role = guild.roles.cache.get('ROLE_ID');

await guild.members.fetch();

setInterval(() => {
    const statuses = Array
       .from(role.members.values())
       .map(member => member.displayName);

    const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
    client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING" })
}, 5000)
```